# Angular skip the get method calling web service

Tags: angularjs

```
    var l = $scope.PendingKOTitems.length,
        k = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < l; k = k + 1) {
        sItemCode = $scope.PendingKOTitems[k]["sItemCode"]
        sOutletCode = $scope.selectedOutlet.sOutletCode;
        sFinal = sOutletCode + "/" + sSubCatgCode

        $http.get(sServiceURL + 'ItemMst/' + sFinal).then(function (resp) {
            $scope.Items = resp.data;
            iindexItem = getIndexOf($scope.Items, sItemCode, "sItemCode");
        }, function (err) {
            console.error('ERR', err);
            // err.status will contain the status code
        })
        sCheckValue = $scope.CheckboxSelection.value;

         $scope.invoice.items.push({
            KOTNo: $scope.KOTNumValue,
            ActiveMode: $scope.lActiveMode,
            SubCatgCode: sSubCatgCode,
            SubCatgDesc: sSubCatgDesc,
            indexSubCatg: iindexSubCatg,
            ItemCode: sItemCode,
            ItemDesc: sItemDesc,
            indexItem: iindexItem,
            Qty: sQty,
            OutletCode: sOutletCode,
            BillType: sBillType,
            MemberCode: sMemberCode,
            RoomNum: sRoomNum,
            BookingCode: dBookingCode,
            TableCode: sTableCode,
            WaiterCode: sWaiterCode,
            UserID: sUserID
        });
    }
```

The get methode not fire in the for loop, after perform for loop it will fire.

I want get 'iindexItem' value for load select based on item sub category. But get method fire after the 'push' operation perform. so i was not able to get 'iindexItem' value. this my problem.

Comment: You can not debug the http request or for that sake in any other object definition. Here you are creating an http get object and so you cannot debug the definition. You can however debug the Callback which would be called once the request is complete and the response have been received.

Comment: We also need the code who call this `http.get`. If there is no call to this, the problem didn't come from the inside of the `http.get`

Comment: you are correct, but i am place this code in for loop. when i try run the above code was skipped but after completion of for loop the above code was executed.

Comment: where is your debugger set? can you please mark it in your code?

Comment: I was mention where I set the breakpoint in my code. And am write this code in Tools for apace cordova for mobile application.

Comment: Do you really need to work with the Promise? Instead of using 'then()' why don't you use 'success()' as 'success()' fires at once.

Comment: I tried 'success()' also but not working. the above I was use some other places and working fine. but in the loop it was not fire and after loop process complete, it was worked. Am just confused.

Comment: @Manivasagan it sounds like a syncrhonous problem. If this code is execute after the end of your loop. It's because the call is made during the loop. But promise are asyncrhonous so, you have the result after the end of the loop

Comment: Thank you @Apédémak, how can resolve this problem? please give me any solution. thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the whole loop where you call this function?

Comment: You have to find a way to syncrhonize everything. But like I said before, we need to see the code in wich you are calling this funtion. Else, we can't really help. I can't guesse the part who need to change on your code if I don't even know the code

Comment: hi @Apédémak, I was post my code above.

Comment: After this for loop, you use your data for what ? Why exactly is it a problem  to have something asynchronous ?

Comment: @Apédémak, I was update my question above. please see and help me for further.

Comment: And what happend if you put your `push` into the `then` of your promise ?

Comment: Sorry am no understand your question @Apédémak

Comment: Currently, the problem is that you are doing your push in the for loop. Your get is asynchronous so, when you do your push, the data arn't already "come back" from the server. Try to put your `push`, into the `then` of your promise. Like this, the data will be add only when you server will give you the data to add.

Comment: you are correct, I will try same method. but it will give wrong output. example the for loop give me a 3 item code. I was put my **push** into **then** at the time last item code only fired up on all three push operation.

Comment: Right, I missed the fact that you calcute some datas at each loop.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and this seems to work fine for me --

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="ctrl">

 <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
 <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var angularapp = angular.module("app",[]);

  angularapp.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$window', '$http', '$filter', '$timeout', MyCtrl]);

  function MyCtrl($scope, $window, $http, $filter, $timeout){

  for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
   $http.get("http://httpbin.org/get").then(function (resp) {
     debugger;
     $scope.Items = resp.data; // here I set my breakpoint
     console.log(i);
     console.log(resp.data);
 }, function (err) {

    console.error('ERR', err);
    // err.status will contain the status code
  });
 }

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The debugger is hit on every iteration in the for loop.

Comment: the debugger hit after the for loop completed. I was post my whole for loop in my question.